# What are reasons "reload!" doesn't always seem to work in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I'm just getting the hang of Rails console, and finding it useful for quickly testing methods in my classes. I know that I can make changes to my Models, then

```
> reload!
```

to grab those updates, but sometimes I'll find that it doesn't seem to reload my latest code. Does Rails cache code somewhere?

In a really simple pseudo example, I may have bad code on line 100:

```
100: u = User.alll
```

and in the Rails console, when I run this method, I might get an error similar to:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `alll' for User:Class ... on line 100
```

then modify my code, fixing the error

```
100: u = User.all
```

then reload:

```
> reload!
```

and then, when calling the method in this class that has the correct code, it still will say

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `alll' for User:Class ... on line 100
```

When clearly, the error is fixed, and the offending line isn't even on line 100 anymore. Is there a way to force/hard-reset the "reload!" command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My guess would be that you're doing something like:

1. Create an instance of `User`
2. Call `someMethod` on the instance
3. You get an error, and you go and fix it
4. `reload!`
5. You call `someMethod` *on the existing instance* and get the error again

So you're calling the method on an instance that hasn't itself been reloaded. Its class has been reloaded, but the instance is already in memory - with bugs and all.

That would be my guess at least (not 100% sure).

Point is, if you create a new instance *after* the `reload!` and call your method on that new instance, it should stop complaining.

Comment: Yes this was exactly the issue. The instances you create don't "reload". After reload!-ing and re-instantiating, things work great each time. Thanks @flambino