# Rails 3 restart console everytime a model is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason in my local environment, every time I change a model, I have to restart my console instead of reloading it. I have cache_classes set to false in my development.rb... any reason why this would be happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235905/what-are-reasons-reload-doesnt-always-seem-to-work-in-the-rails-console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235905/what-are-reasons-reload-doesnt-always-seem-to-work-in-the-rails-console), you type `reload!` in the rails console.