# Reload! Not Working on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reload

This is not the repeat of previously asked question on the same topic.
My Rails version is 3.1.1 and Ruby Version is 1.9.3
I have a model class

```
class TestDistance < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.yo
    puts "yo"
 end

end
```

If i change the method as following

class TestDistance < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 def self.yo
    puts "yo yo"
 end

end
```

`reload!;TestDistance.yo` is not reflecting the change

Console logs are as follows while running rails c

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your development environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log at config/environments/development.rb

Unsupported version: 2.1.9


For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html          


[DEVISE] To select a encryption which isn't bcrypt, you should use devise-encryptable gem.

        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/strexp.rb:41: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route.rb:37: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route.rb:46: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/strexp.rb:41: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route.rb:37: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
/home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route.rb:46: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427596/rails-console-reload-not-reflecting-changes-in-model-files-what-could-be-poss and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235905/what-are-reasons-reload-doesnt-always-seem-to-work-in-the-rails-console

Comment: i have already seen these . . that's y i have mentioned it specifically